# How to identify colums that causes a union error

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, sql-server-2014

I am trying to UNION 25 fields in 40 tables that derives from 10 different DB's.

I received the following error when I tried to union them all together:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

What would be the fastest way to identify which fields are not in the same format, or is there another way to UNION these tables with a "force" command like in SAS.

I am currently using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: it doesn't tell you that the columns type are different among the tables, but rather that you dont have the same number of columns in the SELECT clause of each UNIONed query. Show your SQL

Comment: My guess is that you're using `SELECT *` in one or more places, without actually knowing how many columns you are selecting.  Just craft each `SELECT` to have the same number, and ideally type, for each portion of the `UNION`.

Comment: Comment out one portion of the union and run the query again. If it run successfuly then the problem was in the commented out section.

Comment: Yes, I was using a 'SELECT *'. It works when I specified the fields. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the fastest way is to use `information_schema.columns`.  If, for instance, you are using `select *` for each table, then you can get the offending column(s) by counting the tables where columns appear:

```
select column_name, count(*)
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = @schema and
      table_name in ( . . . )
group by column_name
having count(*) <> 40;
```

I will note that using `select *` for this purpose indicates a poor database design.  Instead of multiple tables with the same format, you should have a single table containing all the data combined.